# on which region this function is analytic

Tags: complex-analysis

If i want to determine the region on which the function 
$f(z) = \frac{z-1}{z^2+4}$
is analytic. Is valid simply take its derivative
$$f'(z) = \frac{-z^2+2z+4}{(z^2+4)^2}$$
and argue, due to this, that $f(z)$ is then analytic in every $z \in \mathbb{C}  : z^2 \neq -4 $ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any rational function is analytic at every point where it's defined. Thus, your conclusion is correct, but you shouldn't take the derivative of a function to see where it's analytic. This is because you're trying to determine where it's complex differentiable in the first place.

Comment: what should i do then  ? are there other options besides check CR and continuity of the partial derivatives? cause this way is too long :c

Comment: @Ariel You unfortunately may need to do that if you have not yet shown that a rational function is analytic everywhere that it is defined, a result which follows from some small yet tedious algebraic facts about analytic functions, namely that analyticity is preserved under addition, products, etc. Alternatively, you can mimic the general proof of this fact for the particular function you are considering.